# Android ScrollView not centering

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, centering, android-scrollview

I have the following code:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">
    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/activity_list_films">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Back"
                android:onClick="back"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

However the button, and the stuff that I add to the inner LinearLayout dynamically, all appear on the top left of the screen. What am I doing wrong?

I have tried putting `layout_gravity="center"` and `gravity="center"` in the inner LinearLayout too, but this does not help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your LinearLayout width is `wrap_content` : it doesn't take the whole width of the screen and cannot center content horizontally. So change it to `android:layout_width="match_parent"` also set `layout_gravity` to `center_horizontal` `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_list_films"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:onClick="back"
                android:text="Back" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please set width -> **match_parent** of LinearLayout

```
      <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"<!--change this one -->
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/activity_list_films">

         <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Back"
            android:onClick="back"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Otherwise you can set you `LinesrLayout` in center. It will be in center of your `ScrollView`.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/activity_list_films"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Back"
            android:onClick="back"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Children of a ScrollView should never have a height to match_parent, it defeats the whole purpose : the content will never be bigger than the scroll view and it won't scroll

Comment: @JulienArzul Thanks for your suggestion and changed code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity = "center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/activity_list_films">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Back"
                android:onClick="back"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You not need to change `Height` of your `Linear Layout` inside `Scroll View`.

If you do that the content inside `Scroll View` will not scroll.

You just need to give `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` inside `Linear Layout` other than keep all the same.

Follow below `Layout`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_list_films"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:onClick="back"
                android:text="Back" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">
    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/activity_list_films">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Back"
                android:onClick="back"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

You are missing fillViewPort for ScrollView